# Why would Android Studio not highlight this const error during editing?

Tags: android-studio, dart

Here I explicitly declare a const variable pointing to a const structure/list.

Maybe I'm expecting too much in these days of super clever lsp type IDE intrspection but why is the IDE not telling me that the "add()" operation is illegal since its on a const?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const questionsAndAnswers = const [
      {'questionText': "What's your favourite colour?",
        'answers': ['Black', 'Green', 'Red', 'White'],
      },
      {'questionText': "What's your favourite animal?",
        'answers': ['Rabbit', 'Snake', 'Elephant', 'Lion'],
      },
      {'questionText': "Who's your favorite instructor?",
        'answers': ['Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max'],
      },

    ];

    questionsAndAnswers.add({"xxx":"yyyy"});
```

Am I misunderstanding const in Dart?

Comment: because that list is not `growable`, and you've got an error because of that, but so it is a `List` it implements all methods (including 'add') and docs clearly says `Fixed-length list. An error occurs when attempting to use operations that can change the length of the list.` 
https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/List-class.html

Answer (score -1):

i'm reading documentation about const keyword in dart.
documentation says:

"The Const keyword in Dart behaves exactly like the final keyword. The only difference between final and const is that the const makes the variable constant from compile-time only. Using const on an object, makes the object’s entire deep state strictly fixed at compile-time and that the object with this state will be considered frozen and completely immutable."

So, probably, Android studio don't highligth nothing because const apply his rules only in runtime.

Example:

```
void main()
{
const var1 = 15;
print(var1);
var1 = 23;
print(var1);
}
```

produce this result:

```
jdoodle.dart:4:5: Error: Can't assign to the const variable 'var1'.
var1 = 23;
^^^^
Command exited with non-zero status 254
```

I post also the difference between final and const keyword.
practically FINAL allow to update a list or array, const not allow this.

FINAL Example:

```
void main()
{
   final array1 = [1,2];
   print(array1);
   array1.add(3);
   print(array1);
}
Result:
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

CONST Example:

```
void main()
{
   const array1 = [1,2];
   print(array1);
   array1.add(3);
   print(array1);
}
Produce:
[1, 2]
Unhandled exception:
Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
#0      UnmodifiableListMixin.add (dart:_internal/list.dart:114:5)
#1      main (file:///home/jdoodle.dart:4:12)
#2      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
Command exited with non-zero status 255
```

Comment: Well, yes. It is. I know. Hence my confusion. The language server / IDE KNOWS its a const though. Why cant it highlight it at edit time?

Comment: because the error is throw only in compile mode.

Comment: Yeds. I get that. But the Q is why. It can be statically determined to be illegal since you cant(should NOT) call add() on a const. hence the exception. You are telling me whats happening, which is fine, but I am asking why the clever editor does not know this will be a 100% runtime error. I would guess that the .add() method isn't annotated to allow the lsp to see it manipulates the const - and that is what surprises me.

Comment: I honestly don't know the technical reasons why the IDE doesn't have this thing.it could be a bug or it could be a technical decision.if you want, open a report on Android studio, so that they can answer you in the most exhaustive way possible. maybe, if we talk about a bug, they could fix it and you could help the whole android world. :)

Comment: sure there are errors that android studio doesn't detect:
example activities not declared in the manifest, or too heavy transactions, etc...